# Paypal Script Working, But No Money Transferred

Tags: php, codeigniter, paypal, paypal-sandbox

i have integrated paypal payment gateway in my script,

i have tested it in paypal sandbox and it worked perfectly. Then i made the script for "paypal live", surely just changed the variable named $environment.

It worked completely without any error, but the problem is that, no money got transferred to the paypal account..

i have checked the paypal api's signatures, etc, and its tottaly okay with that..

but still no money got transferred..

i though i may post it here for some help

```
function paiement_succes()
{
  // Obtain the token from PayPal.
  if(!array_key_exists('token', $_REQUEST)) 
         exit('Token is not received.');
  // Set request-specific fields.
  $token = urlencode(htmlspecialchars($_REQUEST['token']));
  // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
  $nvpStr = "&TOKEN=$token";
  // Execute the API operation; see the PPHttpPost function above.
  $httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('GetExpressCheckoutDetails', $nvpStr);
  if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"])) 
      {
          $this->load->model('payment_model');
          $this->payment_model->paypal_payment();
          $msg = "<label>Thank you !! your payment is successfully done</label>
              <a href='".base_url()."envoie_de_photos/envoyer_vos_photos"."'>Go To Photo Uploading</a>";
          echo $msg;
      } 
  else  
      {
        //exit('GetExpressCheckoutDetails failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
        echo "Payment failed for unknown reason";
      }
}


function pay_by_paypal()
{

        $environment = 'live';
        $_SESSION['item_name']=$this->input->post('item_name');
        $_SESSION['amount']=$this->input->post('amount');
        $_SESSION['currency_code']=$this->input->post('currency_code');
        $_SESSION['no_of_photo']=$this->input->post('no_of_photo');

        $qty=urlencode("1");
        $product_name=urldecode($_SESSION['item_name']);
        $price=urlencode($_SESSION['amount']);
        $currencyID = urlencode($_SESSION['currency_code']);



// or other currency code ('GBP', 'EUR', 'JPY', 'CAD', 'AUD')
     $paymentType = urlencode('Order'); 
     $nvpStr=""; 
     $returnURL = (base_url()."paiement/paiement_succes");
     $cancelURL = (base_url()."paiement/paiement_echec");  
     $i=0;
     $total_amount=0;

     $str = "&METHOD=SetExpressCheckout
&RETURNURL=$returnURL
&CANCELURL=$cancelURL
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NAME0=$product_name
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_NUMBER0=$qty
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT0=$price
&L_PAYMENTREQUEST_0_DESC0=$product_name
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT=$price
&PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE=$currencyID"; 
     $nvpStr=$nvpStr.$str;
$httpParsedResponseAr = $this->PPHttpPost('SetExpressCheckout', $nvpStr);

if("SUCCESS" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]) || "SUCCESSWITHWARNING" == strtoupper($httpParsedResponseAr["ACK"]))
    {
    // Redirect to paypal.com.
    $token = urldecode($httpParsedResponseAr["TOKEN"]);
    $payPalURL = "https://www.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
    if("sandbox" === $environment) 
            {
        $payPalURL = "https://www.$environment.paypal.com/webscr&cmd=_express-checkout&token=$token";
        }
    header("Location: $payPalURL");
    exit;
} 
else  
    {
    exit('SetExpressCheckout failed: ' . print_r($httpParsedResponseAr, true));
}

}

/** SetExpressCheckout NVP example; last modified 08MAY23.
 *
 *  Initiate an Express Checkout transaction. 
*/


/**
 * Send HTTP POST Request
 *
 * @param   string  The API method name
 * @param   string  The POST Message fields in &name=value pair format
 * @return  array   Parsed HTTP Response body
 */
private function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_) {
    //global $environment;
        $environment = 'live';  // or 'beta-sandbox' or 'live'
    // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
    $API_UserName = urlencode('exmaple_api1.sazet_rey.com');
    $API_Password = urlencode('BH89Hx&*09$%bhy65');
    $API_Signature = urlencode('sdfr$%$VGBHHYT899999090-9987777');
    $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.paypal.com/nvp";
    if("sandbox" === $environment) {
        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t.$environment.paypal.com/nvp";
    }
    $version = urlencode('65.0');

    // Set the curl parameters.
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

    // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

    // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
    $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

    // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

    // Get response from the server.
    $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

    if(!$httpResponse) {
        exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
    }

    // Extract the response details.
    $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

    $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
    foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
        $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
        if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
            $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
        }
    }

    if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
        exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
    }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
}
```

i wud appreciate some help regarding this, and i wud be gratefull if anything happens

Comment: Make sure that you're not posting to sandbox. Check the live account as well. All history including IPNs sent by PayPal are logged and available in the PayPal account.

Comment: i am not posting to sandbox

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking and make sure that you are not passing over a variable called "Subject".  It you pass this over, this will then cause your API call to attempt to be passed on the PayPal account you pass over in the subject.  However, you if you did have permissions and got a successful response back, the money would be in that account and not the one that your API credentials from.  If you don't have API permissions you would receive an error indicating this.  Are you getting any kind of response back when you make the API call.  If so what are you getting back?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting emails from PayPal telling you that you received a payment?  If so, check to make sure that the email address on your PayPal account is confirmed.